# What is the difference between this "atomic" Rust code and its "non-atomic" counterpart?

Tags: rust, atomic

I'm fairly new to Rust. I graduated with a Computer Engineering degree 4 years ago, and I remember discussing (and understanding) atomic operations in my Operating Systems course. However, since graduating, I've been working primarily in high-level languages where I haven't had to care about low-level stuff like atomics. Now that I'm getting into Rust, I'm struggling to remember how a lot of this stuff works.

I'm currently trying to understand the source code for the [hibitset](https://github.com/slide-rs/hibitset) library, specifically [atomic.rs](https://github.com/slide-rs/hibitset/blob/master/src/atomic.rs).

This module specifies an `AtomicBitSet` type which corresponds to the `BitSet` type from lib.rs, but using atomic values and operations. From my understanding, an "atomic operation" is an operation that is guaranteed to not be interrupted by another thread; any "load" or "store" on the same value will have to wait for the operation to finish before proceeding. Following from this definition, an "atomic value" is a value whose operations are fully atomic. `AtomicBitSet` uses `AtomicUsize`, which is a `usize` wrapper where all methods are fully atomic. However, `AtomicBitSet` specifies several operations that seem to not be atomic (`add` and `remove`), and there is one atomic operation: `add_atomic`. Looking at `add` vs `add_atomic`, I can't really tell what the difference is.

Here is `add` (verbatim):

```
/// Adds `id` to the `BitSet`. Returns `true` if the value was
/// already in the set.
#[inline]
pub fn add(&mut self, id: Index) -> bool {
    use std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed;

    let (_, p1, p2) = offsets(id);
    if self.layer1[p1].add(id) {
        return true;
    }

    self.layer2[p2].store(self.layer2[p2].load(Relaxed) | id.mask(SHIFT2), Relaxed);
    self.layer3
        .store(self.layer3.load(Relaxed) | id.mask(SHIFT3), Relaxed);
    false
}
```

This method calls `load()` and `store()` directly. I'm assuming that the fact that it's using `Ordering::Relaxed` is what makes this method non-atomic, because another thread doing the same thing to a different index might clobber this operation.

Here is `add_atomic` (verbatim):

```
/// Adds `id` to the `AtomicBitSet`. Returns `true` if the value was
/// already in the set.
///
/// Because we cannot safely extend an AtomicBitSet without unique ownership
/// this will panic if the Index is out of range.
#[inline]
pub fn add_atomic(&self, id: Index) -> bool {
    let (_, p1, p2) = offsets(id);

    // While it is tempting to check of the bit was set and exit here if it
    // was, this can result in a data race. If this thread and another
    // thread both set the same bit it is possible for the second thread
    // to exit before l3 was set. Resulting in the iterator to be in an
    // incorrect state. The window is small, but it exists.
    let set = self.layer1[p1].add(id);
    self.layer2[p2].fetch_or(id.mask(SHIFT2), Ordering::Relaxed);
    self.layer3.fetch_or(id.mask(SHIFT3), Ordering::Relaxed);
    set
}
```

This method uses `fetch_or` instead of calling `load` and `store` directly, which I'm assuming is what makes this method atomic.

But why does the usage of `Ordering::Relaxed` still allow this to be considered atomic? I realize that the individual "or" operations are atomic, but the full method could be run at the same time as another thread. Wouldn't that have an impact?

Moreover, why would a type like this expose non-atomic methods? Is it just for performance? That seems confusing to me. If I were to pick an `AtomicBitSet` over a `BitSet` because it's going to be used by more than one thread, I'd probably want to only use atomic operations on it. If I didn't I wouldn't be using it. Right?

I'd also love an explanation of the comment inside `add_atomic`. As-is it does not make sense to me. Doesn't the non-atomic version still have to care about that? It seems like the two methods are doing effectively the same thing, just with different levels of atomicity.

I'd really just love some help wrapping my head around atomics. I *think* I  understand ordering after reading [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync), but both are still using concepts that I don't understand. When they talk about one thread "seeing" something from another, what does that mean exactly? When it's said that sequentially-consistent operations have the same order "across all threads" what does that even mean? Does the processor change the instruction order differently for different threads?

Answer (score 1):

In the non-atomic case, this line:

```
self.layer2[p2].store(self.layer2[p2].load(Relaxed) | id.mask(SHIFT2), Relaxed);
```

is more or less equivalent to:

```
let tmp1 = self.layer2[p2];
let tmp2 = tmp1 | id.mask(SHIFT2);
self.layer2[p2] = tmp2;
```

so another thread could change `self.layer2[p2]` between the moment it is read into `tmp1` and the moment `tmp2` is stored into it. So if another thread tries to set another bit at the same time, there is a risk that the following sequence occurs:

- thread 1 reads an empty mask,
- thread 2 reads an empty mask,
- thread 1 sets bit 1 of the mask and writes it,
- thread 2 sets bit 2 of the mask and writes it, thus overwriting the value set by thread 1,
- in the end only bit 2 is set!

The same goes for `self.layer3`.

In the atomic case, the use of `fetch_or` guarantees that the whole read-modify-write cycle is atomic.

In both cases, since the ordering is relaxed, the writes to `layer2` and `layer3` may seem to occur in any order as seen from other threads.

The comment inside `add_atomic` is meant avoid an issue when two threads try to add the same bit. Assume that `add_atomic` was written like this:

```
pub fn add_atomic(&self, id: Index) -> bool {
    let (_, p1, p2) = offsets(id);

    if self.layer1[p1].add(id) {
        return true;
    }

    self.layer2[p2].fetch_or(id.mask(SHIFT2), Ordering::Relaxed);
    self.layer3.fetch_or(id.mask(SHIFT3), Ordering::Relaxed);
    false
}
```

Then you risk the following sequence:

- thread 1 sets bit 1 in `layer1` and sees that it wasn't set beforehand,
- thread 2 tries to set bit 1 in `layer1` and sees that thread 1 already set it, so thread 2 returns from `add_atomic`,
- thread 2 executes another operation that requires reading `layer3`, *but `layer3` has not been updated yet, so thread 2 gets a wrong value!*
- thread 1 updates `layer3`, but it is too late.

This is why the `add_atomic` case ensures that `layer2` and `layer3` are set properly in all threads even if it looked like the bit was already set beforehand.